# Rails bootstrap css not loading in correct order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't get this at all, and I am completely stumped.  I have bootstrap, a default css file, and then individual page css files.  My css file looks like this:

```
// Place all the styles related to the Hotel controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
//*= require_self
//*= require jquery.ui.all
//*= require bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss
//*= require defaults.css.scss
//*= require_tree ./hotels
```

This is how it is loading:

```
    <link href="/assets/hotels.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.button.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.slider.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.base.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.all.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/defaults.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/hotels/add_fonts.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/assets/hotels/carousel.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/hotels/carousel_side_text.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/hotels/directions.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/hotels/fileuploader.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/hotels/gmaps4rails.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/hotels/index.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/hotels/specials.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But when I inspect an element in firebug, it is:

[A bunch of stuff from Bootstrap]

[CSS from my default file ]  <----  Being overwritten by bootstrap stuff

[A bunch of stuff from Bootstrap]

So I don't get it.  My defaults are being loaded after the bootstrap, but they are being overwritten by bootstrap.  I don't see how this is possible.

EDITED TO ADD:

This is a span7 div that I am trying to get rid of the left margin on.  Unfortunately, as you can see my overwrite is in the middle of that block.  the margin-left: 0px; is being overwritten.

```
.row-fluid .span7 {
    width: 57.265%;
}
bootst...?body=1 (line 6396)
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5641%;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
bootst...?body=1 (line 6290)
.row-fluid .span7 {
    width: 57.4468%;
}
bootst...?body=1 (line 469)
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.12766%;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
bootst...?body=1 (line 363)
.text-line-buttons {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
**defaul...?body=1 (line 224)
.span7 {
    width: 670px;
}**
bootst...?body=1 (line 6185)
[class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
bootst...?body=1 (line 6141)
.span7 {
    width: 540px;
}
bootst...?body=1 (line 258)
[class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of something being overridden?  Your application.css and the order they are loading look fine to me.

Comment: Edited to add the firebug output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing !important to your css file?
Maybe is annoying but you can try...

[!important css](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)

Comment: The problem is then I can't overwrite my defaults on individual pages.  I've "solved" the problem simply by adding needed components from bootstrap into my other class.  So I deleted the span7 and added width: 52% to my other class.